# How do I install nokogiri 1.7.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nokogiri, bundler, zlib

I tried to install with `bundle` but it gave an error. I *do* have `zlib` installed.

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.7.0.1


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

  Password: 
Installing nokogiri 1.7.0.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/tmp/bundler20171101-9510-jcrqsknokogiri-1.7.0.1/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171101-9510-tlx1ob.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/tmp/bundler20171101-9510-jcrqsknokogiri-1.7.0.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/tmp/bundler20171101-9510-jcrqsknokogiri-1.7.0.1/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/tmp/bundler20171101-9510-jcrqsknokogiri-1.7.0.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  nested_form_fields was resolved to 0.8.2, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
        actionpack was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
          actionview was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
            rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
              nokogiri
chloe@latitude-d430:~/projects/fortuneempire$ apt list zlib*
Listing... Done
zlib-gst/xenial 3.2.5-1build2 amd64
zlib1g/xenial-updates,now 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 amd64 [installed]
zlib1g-dbg/xenial-updates 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 amd64
zlib1g-dev/xenial-updates 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 amd64
zlibc/xenial,now 0.9k-4.3 amd64 [installed]
chloe@latitude-d430:~/projects/$
```

Comment: for Ubuntu run: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` then reinstall `nokogiri`

Comment: That worked. I installed `zlib1g-dev` and it worked. Oh, I thought that was an `l`. The font on StackOverflow is different than the terminal. I don't know why there are so many `zlib` packages.

Comment: Happy that helped! installing `nokogiri`  worked after you installed `zlib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your error is coming from `zlib`:

> zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2

From [this](https://github.com/flapjack/omnibus-flapjack/issues/72) discussion it seems like installing the package might solve the issue:

*for Ubuntu*

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

and then just try installing `nokogiri`:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Although the question is about Ubuntu, I ran into the error on MacOS and this is what worked for me:

For Mac OS Monterey

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

The problem was with the libxml:

```
libxml2 is missing. Please check the mkmf.log to check how it is failing.
```